# Where are the x86_64 packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a x86_64 system. 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux. I'm trying to find packages for netperf. apt-get install doesn't find it. I see the package is available here, but not for x86_64:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/netperf
I must be stupid, can someone point how can I install this package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`netperf` is in `multiverse`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netperf), so you'll need to enable it

Comment: x86_64 means amd64 (so there is a package for you)

Comment: @muru Multiverse is enabled by default.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just booted a VM into a 16.04 ISO to check, and this is what I got: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iBiuB.png Anyway, I'm not getting into another argument with you. Keep your claims.

Comment: @muru In LiveUSB you are correct. But on an installed system it is enabled. Do you ever use Ubuntu? ;-)

Comment: You can test by deleting `/etc/apt/sources.list` and creating a default one. Is that the PROOF?

Comment: We don't know if the OP has Universe enabled or not (might never will), so the default setting should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point you to the package for x86_64 arch.

http://launchpadlibrarian.net/139606892/netperf_2.6.0-2_amd64.deb

These packages have `amd64` in the name.